# What type of Request Data can be Retrieved from ColdFusion Headers?

Tags: coldfusion, header

This is a good way to grab the request before the response: `useragent = getHttpRequestData().headers["User-Agent"];`
What I noticed is that it will not grab the request unless it is on the actual list of header request. An example is I that it seems to only pull the basic request data. For instance if I set the cache control in the web.config file it does set cache, max age and etag, but when setting `etags = getHttpRequestData().headers["ETag"];` and trying to output the data for the ETag generated by the web.config file/server it will not grab the ETag data to output. A few others that I tested are:

```
useragent = getHttpRequestData().headers["User-Agent"];
acceptencoding = getHttpRequestData().headers["Accept-Encoding"];
acceptlanugage = getHttpRequestData().headers["Accept-Language"];
cachecontrol = getHttpRequestData().headers["Cache-Control"];
connection = getHttpRequestData().headers["Connection"];
accept = getHttpRequestData().headers['Accept'];
contentlength = getHttpRequestData().headers['Content-Length'];
```

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to access HTTP headers other than the ones that were sent by the browser/client?

Comment: You should be able to see all of the available information if you dump that method - `writeDump(getHttpRequestData());`

Comment: You could also try using this method instead - `getPageContext().getRequest().getHeader("ETag");` but I'm not sure that will get the information for you either.

Answer (score 0):

Request data is sent from the browser. You can see that with ColdFusion. But IIS sets response headers (such as etag) after ColdFusion is done processing. It's a **response** not a **request**. You cannot see that with ColdFusion, but you can in your browser. EX:

[image]